# revisão-código é uma meta tag?

Tags: debate, meta-tags, tag-específica

Percebi que todas as perguntas na tag [revisão-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digo) se referem não a uma pergunta a respeito do processo de revisão de código (tipo, em "revisões formais do código"), mas sim àquilo que é esperado das respostas (i.e. essa é uma pergunta do tipo *code-review*).

Creio que todos concordamos que *code-review* está dentro do escopo do site, mas é necessário/desejável tagueá-las com [revisão-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digo)? Ou essa tag deveria ser usada somente em perguntas (conceituais, provavelmente) sobre a prática de revisões de código? Note que não adianta [nesse momento] editar a wiki de tag para esclarecer isso, pois se as 4 perguntas atuais tiverem essa tag removida, a tag ficaria com zero perguntas e seria também removida do sistema (certo?).

(A menos é claro que fosse feita pelo menos uma pergunta sobre o assunto. Posso fazer isso em breve, se for do interesse da comunidade.)

Comment: Debate relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/808/devemos-remover-meta-tags

Answer (score 10):

Sendo um ávido utilizador da tag [revisão-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digo) vejo a mesma como uma forma clara e transparente de dizer:

- O código na pergunta funciona
- A pergunta pede melhorias / análise
- As respostas devem salientar erros ou problemas não previstos
- As respostas devem de igual forma apresentar código funcional

Na altura em que criei a tag, foi mesmo com o intuito de marcar as perguntas que caem sobre o escopo do site-irmão https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, dado que revisão ao código está dentro dos tópicos aceites neste site, mas foge das perguntas comuns, daí uma tag para criar a distinção.

Eu acho interessante e útil esta tag porque se alguém precisa de código a funcionar para lidar com um problema, pode usar a pesquisa avançada e localizar código funcional:

[image: Captura Tela]

[Clique para ver pesquisa.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20%5Brevis%C3%A3o-c%C3%B3digo%5D%20%22visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o%22)

Por outro lado, é uma forma bastante prática de diferenciar o *tipo* de pergunta. Na maioria procura-se o problema, nestas não há um problema *per se*!

## Sugestão Tag-Wiki

**Sumário**

Utilizar para perguntas com código funcional que procuram uma análise ao mesmo com especial atenção em Melhoramento, Melhores práticas, Antecipação de problemas, Segurança.

**Descrição**

Utilizar esta tag para colocar perguntas com código funcional, onde o objetivo é obter ajuda da comunidade por meio de análise com vista a:

- Melhorar

  O código pode sempre ser melhorado, simplificado ou atualizado.
- Melhores práticas

  O código pode não estar a seguir todas as inúmeras regras e conselhos para uma correta aceitação do mesmo em múltiplos sistemas.
- Antecipação de problemas

  Prever potenciais problemas ligados à utilização do código e/ou inserção do mesmo no meio de outros blocos de código.
- Aumentar a segurança

  Não fala mais alto que a segurança do código que desenvolvemos, a sua viabilidade e consistência.

Desta forma, estamos a trabalhar em conjunto para melhorar as habilidades dos programadores, pegando em código funcional e tornando-o melhor.

Comment: Na [discussão sobre *code golf*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/desafios-e-code-golf) houve um debate sobre manutenção de uma meta-tag com função parecida à que você propõe. Mas hoje a meta-tag `code-golf` não existe mais.

Comment: Isto são os meus 5cêntimos para o site no que respeita à diferenciação entre perguntas com código para aprimorar e perguntas com código _bugado_! Se existirem alternativas mais eficientes sou o primeiro a apoiar! Mas deixar sem solução não concordo! (não é que a minha opinião valha de muito, mas está expressa... :P)

Comment: Pessoalmente, não sou contra meta-tags, acho que algumas (como esta que propôs) podem ser bastante úteis. Mas [parece haver certo consenso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/808/215) que misturar tags "normais" (i.e. que se aplicam ao *conteúdo* da pergunta, e não à *natureza* da pergunta) com meta-tags é indesejável. Eu seria 100% a favor de um segundo tipo de tag (sei lá, com uma corzinha diferente, que seja) onde se pudesse fazer essa diferenciação que propõe (o exemplo da busca ilustra bem a utilidade prática de se ter meta-tags).

Comment: Eu também sou totalmente favorável à meta-tags em uma ferramenta reformulada. Inclusive poderia ter apenas um *site* em toda a rede se fizessem isto, afinal a ferramenta seria adequada para lidar com isto. Como a ferramenta não funciona assim. Eu sou contra a meta-tags filosóficas. Não acho que elas acrescentam alguma coisa e só expõe um problema ou no *site* ou no tópico dela. Eu acho que a *tag* deturpa o intenção das *tags* que é marcar conteúdo. O dia que a SE resolver criar um mecanismo que **use** as meta-tags, eu apoiarei, como funciona aqui no meta.

Comment: O interessante é que no meta a primeira tag que um usuário coloca precisa necessariamente ser uma dentre as "debate", "suporte", "bug" ou "novo-recurso". Só depois que "desbloqueia" as outras. Se um dos problemas das meta-tags é que elas não podem aparecer sozinhas numa pergunta, por que não só desbloqueá-las depois que a pergunta já tenha pelo menos uma tag normal? Talvez fosse o caso de propor como novo recurso no MSE (se é que isso já não foi feito), o difícil seria obter apoio suficiente.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Força com a proposta! :) Deixa link que o pessoal vai lá apoiar.