# Perguntas tipo "funciona, mas dá pra melhorar?" são válidas?

Tags: debate

Gostaria de saber se são válidas perguntas onde o usuário diz que o código está funcionando, porém quer saber se tem alguma forma melhor para resolver alguma questão.

Por exemplo: redução de código, ou uma forma mais legível de codificar determinada rotina, ou até para um caso de refatoração de códigos.

Me acontece sempre, já que não participo ativamente de nenhum grupo específico relacionado a uma linguagem de programação, e acabo tendo dúvidas se as rotinas que desenvolvi são de acordo com as melhores formas de fazer, ou se preciso refatorar alguma parte de um sistema.

Comment: Eu acabei de responder [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286323/revis%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-programa-que-simula-o-jogo-das-portas-ou-voc%C3%AA-ganha-um-car) de revisão de código, eu pessoalmente gosto desse tipo de pergunta.

Answer (score 10):

**Teoricamente são**, o problema é que uma coisa é melhorar, outra coisa é corrigir algo que funciona a trancos e barrancos, não dá pra por todos no mesmo barco, tem que analisar caso a caso, então não dá para afirmar "categoricamente" que são validas.

Algo que acho interessante é o site https://codegolf.stackexchange.com, não é totalmente a mesma situação, mas é algo que tentaram colocar aqui no site, basicamente para a pergunta ser valida usando a tag [code-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), claro que é possível ter muitas perguntas de baixa qualidade e arrisco dizer que mais de 50% (teoricamente) seriam realmente perguntas ruins.

Vou resumir o "ponto", se a pergunta for bem feita, bem intencionada e não for algo como "façam pra mim" ou "resolvam essa gambiarra pra mim" talvez a comunidade (pessoas) aceitem bem a pergunta.

Claro que vale lembrar que o code-golf tem regras, como menor numero de caracteres, ou como a maneira mais simples (não necessariamente a mais eficiente), o que talvez torne o tópico discutido aqui algo totalmente diferente.

Tirando code-golf (que é algo bem especifico) pode notar que temos um numero razoável de perguntas sobre "como melhorar" (~430 perguntas):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=como+melhorar

Então creio que sempre será caso a caso

Comment: Concordo. Outra tag que encontrei esses dias é a [revisão-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%C3%A3o-c%C3%B3digo) e um meta de [discussão desta tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2594/revis%C3%A3o-c%C3%B3digo-%C3%A9-uma-meta-tag). E acho mais relacionado ao [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) do que ao code golf.

Comment: @danieltakeshi só citei o code-golf como caso semelhante. Porque os sintomas de problemas são semelhantes, a analise infelizmente tem quer ser pergunta a pergunta, não tem como por tudo no "mesmo barco"